# Primefaces components not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, jsf, autocomplete, primefaces, rendering

I'm working on a Spring3/JSF2/Primefaces3.5 application.

The problem I'm facing is that some Primefaces components **(p:autocomplete, p:calendar and p:selectOneMenu)** are not rendering properly in the browser. 
The problem occurs randomly in many pages.
If I reload the page (via F5 key for example) the problem is corrected and the component is rendered as it should.

.xhtml file :

```
<ui:composition  
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:form id="mainForm">

    ....


    <f:validateBean>
        <table class="listing form" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                ...
                (some p:inputText elements)
                ...

            <tr class="bg">
                <td class="first"><strong>Marque :</strong></td>
                <td class="last">
                    <p:autoComplete
                        label="Marque"
                        value="#{montureBean.marque}"
                        completeMethod="#{montureBean.autocompleteMarque}"
                        var="item"
                        itemLabel="#{item.intitule}"
                        itemValue="#{item}"
                        converter="#{montureBean.marqueConverter}"
                        dropdown="true"/>

                    <p:commandLink onclick="dlgMarque.show()"  immediate="true">
                        <img src="/images-main/add-icon.gif" border="0" alt="Ajouter Marque" class="img-action"/>
                    </p:commandLink>
                </td>
            </tr>                                    
            <tr class="bg">
                <td class="first"><strong>Matière :</strong></td>
                <td class="last">
                    <p:autoComplete
                        label="Matière"
                        value="#{montureBean.matiere}"
                        completeMethod="#{montureBean.autocompleteMatiere}"
                        var="item"
                        itemLabel="#{item.intitule}"
                        itemValue="#{item}"
                        converter="#{montureBean.matiereConverter}"
                        dropdown="true"/>

                    <p:commandLink onclick="dlgMatiere.show()"  immediate="true">
                        <img src="/images-main/add-icon.gif" border="0" alt="Ajouter Matière" class="img-action"/>
                    </p:commandLink>
                </td>
            </tr>                                    

        </table>
    </f:validateBean>

    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

Here is an example of generated code for p:autocomplete :

Wrong rendering :

```
    <span aria-multiline="false" aria-disabled="false" role="textbox" id="mainForm:j_id_q_1i" class="ui-autocomplete">
        <input id="mainForm:j_id_q_1i_input" name="mainForm:j_id_q_1i_input" class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-left" autocomplete="off" value="" type="text">
        <input id="mainForm:j_id_q_1i_hinput" name="mainForm:j_id_q_1i_hinput" autocomplete="off" value="0" type="hidden">
        <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-right ui-button-icon-only" type="button">
            <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
            <span class="ui-button-text">&nbsp;</span>
        </button>
        <div id="mainForm:j_id_q_1i_panel" class="ui-autocomplete-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden ui-shadow"></div>
    </span>
```

Correct rendering :

```
        <span id="mainForm:j_id_q_1i" class="ui-autocomplete">
            <input id="mainForm:j_id_q_1i_input" name="mainForm:j_id_q_1i_input" type="text" class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-left" autocomplete="off" value="" />
            <input id="mainForm:j_id_q_1i_hinput" name="mainForm:j_id_q_1i_hinput" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="0" />
            <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-right ui-button-icon-only" type="button">
                <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
                <span class="ui-button-text">&nbsp;</span>
            </button>
            <div id="mainForm:j_id_q_1i_panel" class="ui-autocomplete-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden ui-shadow"></div>
        </span>
        <script id="mainForm:j_id_q_1i_s" type="text/javascript"><!--
            $(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('AutoComplete','widget_mainForm_j_id_q_1i',{id:'mainForm:j_id_q_1i'});});
        //--></script>
```

I noticed that :

- many attributes are assigned to the first span rather than the input,
- the two input elements are not closed in the wrong rendering **>** in place of **/>**
- there is a **javascript function** that appears in the correct rendering that we can't see in the wrong case.

Is it a bug or something wrong I did.
NB : I'm using p:layout for page organisation and f:validation to validate input elements.

Comment: Can you show xhtml page? Especially `DOCTYPE` definition.

Comment: I still don't see `DOCTYPE` definition. Find it somewhere in top-level page as this is part of some template. If it doesn't exist put `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` as first line of top-level `xhtml` file.

Comment: I have an index.xhtml file that calls the above xhtml file via ui:include. the index.html starts with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>   . and the next line contains the doctype as you said :
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally SOLVED!

It was really hard to find out what is wrong with my project as it was happening randomly and affecting many pages.

The problem is that I’m using a “p:panel” updated using the src attribute of “ui:include” like this :

```
<p:panel id="mainPanel">
    <ui:include src="#{menuBean.mainContentPage}.xhtml" />
</p:panel>
```

The menu element just sets the value of “mainContentPage” with the name of the content file (ex. addClient.xhtml, addStore.xhtml ) to show and updates the “mainPanel” via ajax update.

Every .xhtml content file has its own form and components.

The mistake I was making is that all forms in different files had the same id.

```
  <h:form id="mainForm">
          ….commandlinks and components….
  </h:form>
```

I thought it wasn’t really important to give a different name to every form, because the panel is updated with the new content. Unfortunately, the system keeps the form name somewhere and the rendering of the components is compromised.

I changed the id of all forms in my .xhtml files and all works fine.

BIG advice to everyone: **USE DIFFERENT ID FOR EVERY FORM IN YOUR JSF PROJET**.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I follow this but the problème doesn't resolved with IE 11, all works fine with chrome and firefox

Comment: You may have a lot of problems with IE. Personally, I made my application available only for chrome and Firefox. I abandoned adaptation to IE.